# Transition PageCurl to Scroll with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uipageviewcontroller, swift-playground

I would like to change my animation between the view.
Currently i have the PageCurl but i would like to have a Scroll animation like Snapchat.

I can not use the `var transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle { get }`

[image]

**My ViewController :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource{

    let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    var messagesViewController : MessagesViewController!
    var searchViewController : SearchViewController!
    var friendsViewController : FriendsViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set UIPageViewControllerDataSource
        self.dataSource = self

        // Reference all of the view controllers on the storyboard
        self.messagesViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesViewController") as? MessagesViewController
        self.messagesViewController.title = "Messages"

        self.searchViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchViewController") as? SearchViewController
        self.searchViewController.title = "Search"

        self.friendsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("friendsViewController") as? FriendsViewController
        self.friendsViewController.title = "Friends"

        // Set starting view controllers
        var startingViewControllers : NSArray = [self.searchViewController]
        self.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        switch viewController.title! {
        case "Messages":
            return nil
        case "Search":
            return messagesViewController
        case "Friends":
            return searchViewController
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    // pink green blue

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        switch viewController.title! {
        case "Messages":
            return searchViewController
        case "Search":
            return friendsViewController
        case "Friends":
            return nil
        default:
            return nil

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageViewController/transitionStyle):

"The value of this property is set when the page view controller is initialized, and cannot be changed."

You must specify the transition style when you initialize.  If you do that in code, you will need something like:

```
let pageViewController = ViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
```

(Since `ViewController` is a subclass of `UIPageViewController`)

If you are setting up the Page View Controller in a storyboard, amend the transition style in the attributes inspector:

[image: Image of attributes inspector]

Comment: With the last version of Xcode i have choose the "Flip horizontal" in transition style in the playground. but nothing work. I add the let pageViewController too mais but nothing change :/

Comment: `UIPageViewController` has only two transition styles: `Scroll` or `PageCurl`.  `FlipHorizontal` is a `UIModalTransitionStyle` used when a view controller is presented modally.  If you want FlipHorizontal, or something similar, you will need to use something other than a UIPageViewController.

Comment: No i want the same transition than snapchat, how can i do that please.

Comment: How do you create the above ViewController?  Via a storyboard/segue or in code?

Comment: I have create my view controller on the playground with the same name in the code paste in the question.

Comment: You should use the line `let pageViewController = ....` directly in the playground - you don't need to add it to the start of your class definition.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use storyboard and still need to set the transition style in code you can use this trick in the Class you made inheriting UIPageViewController. The trick is that in the init with coder you call super.init() which takes transition style like this

```
class ViewController: UIPageViewController {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: Configs.transitionStyle, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but it botthers me not calling the init(coder:) initializer... I'm not sure if we're supposed to do this...