# UI Swipe Gestures in xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

my question is regarding swipe gestures. I wanna add four gestures positions to my array of quotes. quotes = ["no1", "no2", "no3]
I want to add 4 positions to my quotes i.e. up, down, left,right. The transition i want to add is "Partial Curl", so that it would swipe as if you are reading a book. And also each array should be displayed separately after being swiped. 
So that it appears like this. "no1" after being swiped left and up. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What about using `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: like as if you are reading a book. So on page 1 "no1" would appear. After swiping next "no2" should appear. And same goes when you go back. You should swipe right to go back from "no2" to "no1". And also the transition should be if you wanna go next, the transition should be partial curl and also you should be able to go next through "book-like" swiping or "button-like" tapping by tapping towards the left. Hope it helps. let me know plz. Thanks

Comment: [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) is what are you looking for. You might also want to check [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014852/transition-pagecurl-to-scroll-with-uipageviewcontroller) for achieving the "Partial Curl" transition effect

Comment: Sorry maybe i didnt cleared myself well enough. I am not only looking for partial curl effect but i want my quotes to appear on different views as well when the user swipes. And at the moment i am unable to do it.

Comment: Well, I think you might want to check http://mathewsanders.com/animations-in-swift-part-two/